# How to delete, not hide, received recommendation on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I received a LinkedIn recommendation from a colleague.  I no longer want it.

How do I *delete* it, and not merely hide it from others' view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the recipient of the recommendation, you can only "*hide*" it on your profile; but you can ask the person who wrote the recommendation to "*delete*" it.